# Jenkins Puppet integration

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, puppet, continuous-deployment

My development setup is such that for every svn checkin code is built,unit tested, packaged and published in Artifactory. Now I want to automate my deployment process & run integration(Selenium) test as part of this process. I am thinking of using Puppet to managed the deployment

1. Is puppet the correct tool for this
2. What is the process I should use to trigger puppet master to initiate a fresh installation on agents, I couldn't find any Jenkins plugin that would actually trigger puppet. One option is to call

   puppet apply ...

   as a Jenkins post build task

Any suggestions welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this Selenium Jenkins article](https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium-jenkins/) from Saucelabs, a service that automates cross-browser testing. Though they are a vendor with a service to sell, the article covers how to do Selenium testing yourself with Jenkins. It also exposes common pain points you are likely to run into with this approach.

A Puppet master doesn't serve the function of orchestrating client convergences. Take a look at Mcollective. This is a tool that will allow you to trigger puppet runs on target systems from a Jenkins agent via script commands.

Some Mcollective getting started material:

- http://www.slideshare.net/PuppetLabs/presentation-16281121
- http://puppetlabs.com/mcollective